# Error message installing Ricci

Tags: physics, packages, tensors

I just started using Mathematica. With the goal of solving
a Loop  integrals over a scalar gravity interaction. For the tensor calculus necessary i wanted to use, Ricci. [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/.](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Ricci/) However when loading this package I get the following error message.

[image]

The error message occurs as can be seen from the screenshot. Wenn I input the command Needs["Ricci`"].

Which leaves me with three question.

1. What does an error message mean and how do I get rid of it.
2. Are they are better packages for this use case.
3. How do I deinstall if necessary a packages in mathematic.

the commands included in Ricci are suggested by the   Autocompletion of Mathematic. However they do not give output described in the user manual.

The file Ricci.m is located at my PC> Documents>…>packages. As far as I can tell dos this path not
Occur when i execute the command $Path in the file.
If I do this it gives the following path

```
In[]=$Path

Out[]={"C:\\Users\\ToniT\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\\
DocumentationIndices", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\SystemFiles\\Links", \
"C:\\Users\\ToniT\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Kernel", "C:\\Users\
\\ToniT\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Autoload", \
"C:\\Users\\ToniT\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications", \
"C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\\Kernel", "C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\
\\Autoload", "C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\\Applications", ".", \
"C:\\Users\\ToniT", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\
\\13.1\\AddOns\\Packages", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\SystemFiles\\Autoload", "C:\\Program \
Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\AddOns\\Autoload", \
"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\AddOns\\Applications", "C:\\Program \
Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\AddOns\\ExtraPackages", \
"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Packages", \
"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\Documentation\\English\\System", \
"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\SystemFiles\\Data\\ICC", "C:\\Program \
Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.1\\Documentation\\ChineseSimplified\\System\
\\"}’
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Use `<<Ricci.m` as it says on the documentation page. This file should be accessible to Mathematica. Is this file in a directory that is on `$Path` ?

Comment: Yes it appears that way, see the comment i have posted below.

Comment: **1** Where is the file `Ricci.m` located? **2** Is that directory on `$Path` (yes or no)?  **3** Does the package install or are there errors? **4** If so, append error messages to post. **5** Delete your answer, and add requested info to your post.

Comment: 1 Ricci.m is located at a subfolder calld my Computer/This PC. I run Mathematica on Windows  11. As I understand it, this subfolder does not appear on '''$Path.